# Can this property be treated as a sufficient condition for continuity?

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

Let $f(x)$ be defined on $\mathbb{R}$ and have this property:

$$|f(x)-f(y)| \leqslant |x-y|^\alpha,\qquad 0<\alpha<1$$

Is this sufficient to claim that $|f(x)|$ is continuous?

I couldn't think up of an counterexample. As I understand, if it exists it must be a function with a removable or jump discontinuity.

Also, the statement hints somewhat at the definition of uniform continuity, but I couldn't think of any root properties that could help show equivalence.

Comment: It is [Hölder condition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hölder_condition), right?

Comment: By the way, what you have at hand is even stronger than uniform continuity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's' sufficient by definition of continuity with epsilon-delta. Namely let $a\in\Bbb R$ and let us show $f$ is continuous at $a$.

So let $\varepsilon>0$: we have to find $\delta>0$ so that $$\forall x\in\Bbb R,|x-a|<\delta\Rightarrow ||f(x)|-|f(a)||\leq\varepsilon.$$
Clearly, $\delta:= \varepsilon^{\frac{1}{\alpha}}$ is ok because if $|x-a|<\varepsilon^{\frac{1}{\alpha}}$, then $||f(x)|-|f(a)||\leq |f(x)-f(a)|\leq |x-a|^{\alpha}< \varepsilon$. Here we used the reverse triangle inequality.

Comment: Thank you so much! So a monotonic transformation of an inequality is the key.